# my first lookahead (or lookbehind?) exercise

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

```
8:9 DAR4:3], 23.98 fps
8:9 DAR4:3], 29.97 fps
8:9 DAR4:3], 25 fps
```

I've got these 3 possible strings, and I'm looking for an expression that will extract the numbers which occur between the first comma in this line, and the " fps".

either 23.98, 29.97, 25

How best to attack this? Looking behind to whatever digits and dots [\d.] fall before " fps" seems the most logical way but I've never done one of these.

An example, please?

I have this already,

```
\d{2}\.\d{2}|25
```

but I'm afraid the "25" could pick up false positives from somewhere later in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=, )[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(?= fps)
```

should work fine and will **only** match your numbers.

[image: match result]

[**Regex101 demo**](http://regex101.com/r/aS5aK1)

Comment: `8:9 DAR4:3], 25 fpssssssssdfsssdssfsdsfsssdfsssdfsfpsfpfps` this will pass.

Comment: @progenhard OP never mentioned that it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

```
,\s*(\d+\.?\d*)\s*fps$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/dRoea_DKxYN5YscV)

Maybe this will work?

- `,` indicates the the comma
- `\s*` indicates zero or more spaces.
- `(\d+\.?\d*)` captures decimal values in a capture group
- `\s*` indicates zero or more spaces.
- `fps$` checks to see if fps is at the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks - I see what's going on. I'm going to post a new question now.